# Selecting a subset of functions from a list of functions in python

Tags: python

I have a list: `mylist = [1,2,5,4,7,8]`
I have defined a number of functions that operate on this list. For example:

```
def mean(x): ...
def std(x): ...
def var(x): ...
def fxn4(x): ...
def fxn5(x): ...
def fxn6(x): ...
def fxn7(x): ...
```

Now I am given a list of function names that I want to apply on mylist.

for ex:  `fxnOfInterest = ['mean', 'std', 'var', 'fxn6']`

What is the most pythonic way to call these function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that there is a pythonic™ way to solve the question. But in my code it's quite a common situation, so I've written my own function for that:

```
def applyfs(funcs, args):
    """
    Applies several functions to single set of arguments. This function takes
    a list of functions, applies each to given arguments, and returns the list
    of obtained results. For example:

        >>> from operator import add, sub, mul
        >>> list(applyfs([add, sub, mul], (10, 2)))
        [12, 8, 20]

    :param funcs: List of functions.
    :param args:  List or tuple of arguments to apply to each function.
    :return:      List of results, returned by each of `funcs`.
    """
    return map(lambda f: f(*args), funcs)
```

In your case I would use it the following way:

```
applyfs([mean, std, var, fxn4 ...], mylist)
```

Note that you really don't have to use function *names* (as you would have to do in, for example, PHP4), in Python function is the callable object by itself and can be stored in a list.

**EDIT:**

Or possibly, it would be more pythonic to use list comprehension instead of `map`:

```
results = [f(mylist) for f in [mean, std, var, fxn4 ...]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the functions by their names with:

```
map(globals().get, fxnOfInterest)
```

And then loop over them and apply them to the list:

```
[func(mylist) for func in map(globals().get, fxnOfInterest)]
```

Comment: excellent answer, upvoted. In case it were necessary to check the name provided refers to a callable add `if hasattr(func, '__call__')` to the list comprehension (use `callable(func)` on python 3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`

```
mylist = [1,2,5,4,7,8]
fxnOfInterest = ['mean', 'std', 'var', 'fxn6']
for fn in fxnOfInterest:
    print eval(fn+'(mylist)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example , I think nothing could be more pythonic than this , 
I call it a function dispatcher.

```
dispatcher={'mean':mean,'std':std,'var':var,'fxn4':fxn4}
try:
    for w in fxnOfInterest :
        function=dispatcher[w]
        function(x)
except KeyError:
    raise ValueError('invalid input')
```

Each time function will get value according to `dispatcher` dictionary,
When you in Rome do Like Romans .

Comment: i.e. map them manually. But it is unnecessary, since Python has many means of introspection